# Going Back is showing Black Screen in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am trying to use `Navigator.pop(context);` in an appbar but the problem is that it shows a black screen and then you have to press the back button on android then it pops current black screen, so where is this black screen coming from that I don't know and in iPhone there is no back button so that why it is stuck in that screen. Please do help me

This is the code where I am using this Navigator code.

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return new Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(30, 30, 30, 1.0),
  appBar: new AppBar(
    elevation: 0.0,
    backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(30, 30, 30, 1.0),
    actions: <Widget>[
      new IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings_power),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }),
    ],
    title: new Text(
      "PROLOG",
      style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
 );
}
```

and the most strange thing is that I am using this piece of code in another class its working fine. So where is the problem...

Comment: Checked it. All works fine. Could you past more code? Maybe there is something

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky its fixed

Comment: So, what was the cause of this bug?

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky I was trying to call the statelesswidget but after calling that and calling the Navigator code its first opens the black screen from nowhere

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky thanks for your help

Comment: @AnasReza Thanks for the help. you should post your comment as an answer

Comment: Post the answer so that it can help others too

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you're getting a black/blank screen after calling `Navigator.pop(context)` is because there's no widget/screen beyond the current [`Navigator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html) stack.

In Flutter, `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop')` is used to remove the topmost Flutter instance. As mentioned in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html), the method should remove the current Activity from the stack in Android. The behavior is a bit different on iOS though.

If you're trying to implement this function to close the app, **this is highly discouraged**. This is pointed out on [Apple's archived doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1561/_index.html). I'm trying to search for an updated reference, but navigating through Apple's Developer docs is challenging.

Anyway, I've made some changes to your code snippet if you'd like to try this out.

Add this in your imports

```dart
import 'dart:io' show Platform, exit;
```

As for the code, [`exit(int)`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/exit.html) is used for iOS. It's recommended to use an exit code from the range 0...127 as mentioned in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/exit.html). While `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop')` is used for other platforms (mainly Android in this case).

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(30, 30, 30, 1.0),
    appBar: new AppBar(
      elevation: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(30, 30, 30, 1.0),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings_power),
          // if Platform is iOS call exit(0)
          // else call the preferred method
          // https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html
          onPressed: () => Platform.isIOS
              ? exit(0)
              : SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop'),
        ),
      ],
      title: new Text(
        "PROLOG",
        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
  );
}
```

Demo

[image]